# Recursive Ascending and Recursive Descending Order Functions for a Linked List

Tags: c++, sorting, recursion, linked-list

This is a homework assignment, I've written most of the code already, the only thing I can't figure out is that I have to have a recursive function to sort the linked list in ascending order, and a recursive function to sort the linked list in descending order. I'm pretty lost.

Here is my entire code.

```
using namespace std;

struct ListNode;
typedef ListNode* ListPtr;

struct ListNode
{
    int number;
    ListPtr next;

    ListNode(int value, ListPtr ptr = NULL)
    {
        number = value;
        next = ptr;
    }
};

char Menu();
void Add(ListPtr &, int);
void Delete(ListPtr &, int);
void Ascend(ListPtr &);
void Descend(ListPtr &);
void Print(ListPtr &);
void DeleteList(ListPtr &);

int main()
{
    ListPtr head = NULL;
    char answer;
    int input;

    answer = Menu();
    while(answer != 'Q')
    {
        if(answer == 'A')
        {
            cout << "Please enter in an integer: ";
            cin >> input;
            Add(head, input);
        }
        else if(answer == 'D')
        {
            cin >> input;
            Delete(head, input);
        }
        else if(answer == 'P')
        {
            Ascend(head);
        }
        else if(answer == 'O')
        {
            Descend(head);
        }
        else if(answer == 'N')
        {
            Print(head);
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Incorrect input, please try again.\n";
        }

        answer = Menu();
    }

    DeleteList(head);
    return 0;
}

char Menu()
{
    char uinput;

    cout << "Please enter in one of the following:\n";
    cout << "A: Add an item to the end of the list.\n";
    cout << "D: Delete an item from the list.\n";
    cout << "P: Print the list in ascending order.\n";
    cout << "O: Print the list in descending order.\n";
    cout << "N: Display the number of items in the list.\n";
    cout << "Q: Quit.\n";

    return toupper(uinput);
}

void Add(ListPtr &start, int item)
{
    if(start->number > item || start == NULL)
        start = new ListNode(item, start);
    else
        Add(start->next, item);
}

void Delete(ListPtr &start, int item)
{
    if(start != NULL)
    {
        if(start->number == item)
            ListPtr cur = start;
        start = start->next;
        delete cur;
    }
    else
    {
        Delete(start->next, item);
    }
}

void Ascend(ListPtr &start)
{

} 

void Descend(ListPtr &start)
{

}

void Print(ListPtr &start)
{
    ListPtr cur = start;
    int count = 0;

    if(cur == NULL)
    {
        cout << "The list is empty.\n";
    }
    else
    {
        if(cur != NULL)
        {
            if(count % 10 == 0)
                cout << endl;
            cout << setw(5) << cur->number;
            cur = cur->next;
            count++;
        }
    }
    cout << endl;
}


void DeleteList(ListPtr &start)
{
    if(start != NULL)
    {
        DeleteList(start->next);
        cout << "Deleting item " << start->number << endl;
        delete start;
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO!  Especially with so much code, formatting it consistently will help people read it to help you.  Also, be sure to explain what is not working, what you have tried etc.

Comment: What exactly is your problem? The logic of the function? Are you familiar with recursive functions and how to write one?

Comment: Sup guys, and sorry I'm pretty new to how to write it out, I'm in a c++ programming 2 class and both programming 1 and 2 are introductory level.  The problem is I have no idea how to write these two pieces, the ascend function should take the numbers in the list and print them out in ascending order, and the descend function in descending order.  I'm only allowed to use one loop (my menu function) so these 2 functions have to be recursive.  We've done a few recursive assignments so I understand them on a basic level, but we just started linked lists so combining it with recursion is confusing.

Comment: It compiles so far, except for line 102 - in void Delete function, "cur" is not declared in this scope.

Answer (score 0):

For the recursion part, one method is to recursively divide the lists into two lists, left and right, until the list size is reduced to 1 (or zero) in which case the recursive function just returns the list, else it's followed by code in the recursive function that merges the returned left and right lists, and returns the merged list.

Have you learned how to split a linked list into two lists? Normally this is done using two pointers. I'm not sure what you've been taught and what you're supposed to figure out. What level of programming class is this?

Comment: It's a programming 2 with c++ class, introductory level.  I also haven't learned to split a linked list in two yet.  The purpose is to be able to select an option from the menu to print out the list (from integers I've entered like say 5, 10, and 6) in either ascending or descending order.

Comment: Using two pointers in addition to the head pointer, ptr2 = ptr1 = head, advance one pointer twice (ptr2 = ptr2->next->next) and the other once (ptr1 = ptr1->next) until ptr2 reaches the end of the list, in which case ptr1 is the mid point of the list. You'll need to check for NULLs for both ...->next and ...->next->next when advancing ptr2 or ptr1. Then ptr2 = ptr1->next, ptr1->next = NULL. First half of list starts at head, second list starts at ptr2.

Comment: You could also use two counters while doing this, cnt2 += 2 when ptr2 = ptr2->next->next, cnt1 += 1 when ptr1 = ptr1->next. After ptr2 reaches end of list, correct cnt2 = cnt2 - cnt1. Then by passing pointers and counts, the code just advances one pointer (count/2) times to reach the mid point.